# Plotting sfc_POLYGON in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf

I have a sfc_POLYGON, `IHS` obtained as a union of a few shapes using the `sf` package.

```
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 270194.7 ymin: 2255850 xmax: 279225 ymax: 2265469
epsg (SRID):    32643
proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
POLYGON((279224.998943279 2261084.1514869, 2792...
```

While I am able to plot this in `mapview`, I am facing some problems while plotting the same in `leaflet`. When I plot this is `leaflet`, I get a warning `sf layer is not long-lat data` which it isn't, and I get the base world map. This is the code I used for plotting in `leaflet`.

```
IHS%>%leaflet()%>%addTiles()%>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group ="ESRI")%>%
  addPolygons()
```

I suspect this has to do something with the CRS. I have tried `st_set_crs(IHS, 4326)`which changes my projection of `IHS` from utm to longlat:

```
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 270194.7 ymin: 2255850 xmax: 279225 ymax: 2265469
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

However there is no change in the leaflet warning and output. I am not sure here, but has it got something to do with changing the dimension and bbox (which appears to be in meters)?

Comment: what does the `POLYGON((...))` line in the output now show when you print `IHS` to the console?

Comment: `POLYGON((279224.998943279 2261084.1514869, 2792...`

Comment: Therefore it's not in Lon/ Lat

Comment: Yes, so is there a way to convert it to Lon/Lat?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Converting" into Lon/Lat is to change its **spatial projection**. Once you know that, you can play with spatial data and find in library help the correct way of projecting spatial features.

In your case, using `st_set_crs(IHS, 4326)` only says that the projection is Lon/lat, without projecting it.
You need to use `st_transform`:

```
IHS_wgs84 <- st_transform(IHS, "+init=epsg:4326")
```

Comment: Thanks @StatnMap, didn't realize that `st_set_crs()` doesn't actually transform it!

Comment: When I use transformed_shapefile <- st_transform(shapefile, "+init=epsg:4326") I get a message "GDAL Message 1: +init=epsg:XXXX syntax is deprecated. It might return a CRS with a non-EPSG compliant axis order."When I use transformed_shapefile <- st_transform(shapefile, 4326) I don't get the message.